# Coins sent without downloading the full wallet

Tags: wallet, altcoin, wallet-recovery

i sent bit-connect tokens to my desktop wallet and now i cant seem to see them can you please help me it says on the block explorer that it is already there but the network is updated. after that transaction i sent another one which came to the address can you please help? Are my coins gone?

Comment: Presumably you are talking about [this altcoin](https://bitconnectcoin.co/).Was your wallet of a type specifically designed for BitConnect coins? If not, then it won't detect them, but if you can get the private key from that wallet then they may still be recoverable.

Comment: Yes the wallet it is specifically for this altcoin and i can see the confermation in the blockchain https://www.blockexperts.com/bcc/address/8Y7D6YfD7htnQ7uYaDHZzQSHtjiXRZfsZ9

Comment: Has the wallet fully synchronised?

Comment: yes it has but i dont see my tokens

Comment: Have you double checked that the address exactly matches? If so, then perhaps there's a bug in the wallet. If it's a type of wallet that relies on 3rd party blockchain data, it could also be worth restarting the wallet or otherwise forcing it to connect to a different server.

Comment: how may i be able to do that i think the BCC blockchain only has 1 wallet. how can i connect to a diffrent server

Comment: is therea way i can contact you via direct msg or dm?

Comment: Without knowing more about it, I can't say. As an example, in Electrum, there is a Tools > Network window that indicates the server in use. When Electrum is restarted, a different random selection of server is made.

Comment: Best to keep details in this question, as someone else might be able to help.

Comment: What's the name of the wallet you're using? (Even if there's only one wallet available now, there may be more over time, and this question will be around for a long time)

Comment: Bitconnect is a scamcoin.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, if you:

1. have the private key for the receiving address the funds have been sent to
2. can still see the expected balance for the receiving address in the appropriate block explorer for BitConnect
3. can confirm the receiving address was correctly generated from the private key (eg by importing the private key to a freshly installed wallet, and checking the receiving address)

Then your funds should be retrievable, somehow (but you may need to resolve an issue with the wallet).

Firstly, I'd recommend ensuring you have a safely stored backup of the private key(s) for your funds.

Then, you may like to try re-installing the wallet, or deleting some of its data so that it re-sync's from the network.

Comment: but there is one error I sent another amount and the wallet received that but the weird thing is the first one didn't come